# Char Append in String at Run Time Error Variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, string

For Example I'm having an error if want to printout the `cipher` String after end of `for` loop:

```
System.out.print("Cipher Text IS : >>> ");
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    char a = plainText.charAt(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < allChar.length(); j++)
    {
        if (allChar.charAt(j) == a)
        {
            char c = allChar.charAt(j + key);
            String cipher = "null" + c;

            System.out.print("\t" + c);
        }
        System.out.println(cipher);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Sir i got the point i don't initialize the cipher string before the for loop i define the string in the boundary of for loop thats why when i want to access it out of boundary then it's give an error Thanks for your comment ...

Comment: Please keep the question as it was, when your question was solved. Just accept the answer which helped you to solve the problem.

Comment: @Tom i have a question can you kindly do answer me ???

Comment: If you have another question, then create one by clicking on the "Ask Question" button in the top right corner. So please stop changing your question after it was solved. This is not how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: @Tom stackoverflow not allow me to ask another question it's say you reached your limit and wait 3 days :(

Comment: There is a limit for new users (with less than 50 reputation points) so you either have to wait or you can create another account (which is "ok", if you don't use it to avoid question bans (you get them be asking several _bad_ questions); you're currently not bad, so no worries about that).

Comment: @Tom are you have facebook account ??? can you tell me how i increase my reputation ??? i have a project in java i want some one fully help me you have very nice skills can you do help ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this (see my comments inline):

```
for(int j=0; j<allChar.length(); j++)
{
    if(allChar.charAt(j) == a)                   
    {
        char c= allChar.charAt(j+key);
        String cipher = "null"+c;

        System.out.print("\t"+c );
    }
    System.out.println(cipher);
    // cipher is not defined / initialzed here.
    // this is not the "end" of the loop but within its body,
    // thus prints on every iteration
}
```

to:

```
cipher  = ""; // initalize cipher
for(int j = 0; j < allChar.length(); j++)
{
    if(allChar.charAt(j) == a)                   
    {
        char c= allChar.charAt(j + key);
        cipher += "null"+c; // don't know the logic here!

        System.out.print("\t" + c);
    }
}
System.out.println(cipher); // print result after loop
```

Comment: Nice Answer Sir Axel i got your point very well but have a little problem more can you kindly help me i post a answer a code of ATBASH cipher but it's giving an error can you kindly check it please ...

Comment: Sir i have a question are you there ??

Answer (score 0):

Running Code for ATBASH Cipher Thanks for Help Dears

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

  class Asif
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
       {
       String allchar = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
       Scanner a= new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter the plainText For Cipher here ");
       String plainText=a.nextLine();
       plainText=plainText.replaceAll(" ", "");
       plainText=plainText.toUpperCase();
       int len= plainText.length();
       int len1 = allchar.length();
       String cipher="";

       for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
       {
           char b=plainText.charAt(i);
           for(int j=0; j<26; j++)
           {
               char c=allchar.charAt(j);
               if(c == b )
               {
                   int index=allchar.indexOf(c);
           int position=25-index;
                   cipher+= allchar.charAt(position);
                   break;

               }
           }
       }
       System.out.println(cipher);       
     }
 }
```

Comment: you should post new questions as new question. not as self-comment or self-answer so that community can view and participate!

Comment: @AxelAmthor I don't think that this is supposed to be a question. This is more likely the full code he now uses. There was also another "answer" which was a new question, but it is deleted now.

Comment: sir this time my question is about handwriting control recognizer in java i want some directions can you help ??

Comment: @AxelAmthor Ok, then please show me the sentence "i have a question" in this answer. While you're searching, please rethink my sentence *"There was also another "answer" which was a new question, but it is deleted now."*. There _was_ a second answer from him which was about his new question, but it is deleted now. It is not related to this answer.

Comment: we have 2 meanwhile: just above your post and in the OP's self-answer

Comment: @AliHamdani Any new question belongs in to the comments thread! Open a new question from scratch, if you want anyone of the community including me to answer / "give directions"